# How can I collect order delivery date/time in Store?

Tags: expresso-store

Any ideas on how I could collect order delivery date/time in Store.

Best wishes
Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a custom order field and then output that in the checkout process.

Store > Settings > Order Fields. Pick an available field and give it a name ('Delivery Date' for instance).

Then output this as normal in the checkout. You can use it in combination with [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to provide a date selection widget and set the correct formatting automatically. Or if you need the time included in the same field as well then I look to use [jQuery DateTimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/). You have lots of control here when it comes to date and time selection.

That combination works very well and can be pulled through into the Store order confirmation emails too.